# Cannot access Thingsboard CE UI via localhost or public IP in Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, thingsboard

I have successfully installed **ThingsBoard CE 3.6.2** on an Azure Ubuntu 20.04 VM Instance by referring the ThingsBoard Ubuntu [Installation Guide](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/ubuntu/?ubuntuThingsboardQueue=inmemory)

Here is my Azure Configuration:

- **Operating System:** Linux (ubuntu 20.04)
- **Size:** Standard B2s
- **vCPUs:** 2
- **RAM:** 4 GiB
- **Public IP:** Assigned (Static)

I am also using Azure Postgres SQL as my Database

After setting everything up and installing thingsboard i tried accessing the UI using `http://[public-ip]:8080/` and `http://[public-ip]/` both using firefox browser where it just loads for sometime and says connection timed out and also using curl where im failing to get response for above addresses as well as curl localhost is also failing

Note that i have assigned inbound rules for ports TCP 22,80,443,1883 and UDP 5683

Here are my configuration and log files

- [/var/log/thingsboard/install.log](https://pastebin.com/wFCU80n1)
- [/var/log/thingsboard/thingsboard.log](https://pastebin.com/Eat5UeRv)
- [/usr/share/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.conf](https://pastebin.com/ifxR6JPC)
- [/usr/share/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.yml](https://pastebin.com/xVV3Ktex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically the thing is i'm dumb :)

I thought that allowing http traffic on port 80 is same as post 8080, after adding port 8080 to inbound rules its running smoothly sry im noob